# How to hide page number on first page?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I have setup a document with page numbers within the footnote. Now I want to hide the number for the first page as it is the document's cover sheet.

Comment: i don't think so it's possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of quite recently (24-02-2015) it is possible in Google Documents to have a different page numbering, with regards to the first page.

### Quote

Text posted on the Google+ Google Docs page:

```
Headers and Footers - the way you want them
One of your biggest requests (especially those of you who use Docs to write 
academic papers) is to be able to customize how headers and footers appear 
on the first pages of your documents. 

With today’s updates, you can now use different headers and footers on the 
first pages of your documents, which comes in handy for:
> Following academic formatting guidelines (e.g. MLA, CMS, APA)
> Starting page numbering on the second page
> Making a title page without headers or footers

After inserting a header or footer in your document you’ll see a new checkbox
--just tick it and you’ll be able to set a different header and footer on the 
first page.

There’s also a new Insert > Page Number menu that lets you customize how and 
where you start your page numbers--like on the bottom of the second page, 
for example.
```

### Screenshots

[image]

### Note

It might take a while for the feature to be available as it's being rolled out.

### Reference

- https://plus.google.com/112520969446868076741/posts/TovBH2EPCpL

Comment: Do you know if there is a method like this, still counting the 1st page as 1, yet not showing the 1 on the page. Showing 2, 3, 4... Just suppressing the 1 being shown?

Answer (score 17):

This has been a [feature request](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/docs/RAlw_h8pYMU) for a very long time. This functionality is not currently available.

Answer (score 9):

Create a white box using the Drawing feature. Place it over the number. That is what I had to do. Unless you want the number on the next page to be 1. :)

Comment: Good idea, but I can't seem to do this with the current Google Docs. I created the white box, but the only allowed placement formats are "￼In line", "Wrap text", "Break text". None of these let me hover the box over the text at arbitrary locations on the page. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

As per Izzy's response, if you make two files: one with the title page/pages where you don't want page numbers and the rest where you do want page numbers, separately, then you could export as a PDF and merge both(there are thousands of services online, for no good reason I use http://foxyutils.com/mergepdf/). This would make page number 1 in the second document, of course, but maybe that's what you want? I know this is a longer way but if you don't have MS Word or Libreoffice...

(Also, sorry, I know this would better be suited as a comment but I haven't got 50 rep yet)

Comment: By the way for Linux, there is [PDFShuffler](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pdfshuffler/) that is great for graphically merging PDFs.

Comment: Or [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) which is less graphical but, because it's command line, I think is faster and cleaner to use

Answer (score 0):

It is possible easily,
1st give the page numbering as always, it will start from page no. 1 from 1st page. Now goto Insert Tab -> Header & Footer Group -> Page Number -> Format Page Number and Click "Start At : 0" (Type 0 )
Now you will see that the numbering will start from 0.
Now to hide the numbering from 1st page -> Again goto Insert Tab-> Header Footer Group -> Click edit Header -> Remove Tick from "Different 1st Page"